# Mixing extensions that do and don't use the Add-on Service in Site 9.1

Tags: sites-9.1, add-on

In Tridion Sites 9.1, is it possible to have a mix of extensions that do and do not use the Add-on Service?

For example, could I have a GUI Extension that I've downloaded from the SDL App Store that needs deploying using the Add-on Service alongside some other legacy GUI extension that I've deployed 'manually'? (As long as these don't impact one-another, obviously).

I would assume that I can and that the manually deployed extensions just don't appear in the **Add-ons** section of the GUI, but was hoping someone could confirm before I start my upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but only for CM side extensions. For CD, it's either the old way OR the add-on mechanism.

Comment: Hi Atila. Thanks for the answer. Is this documented anywhere, do you know, or just something you found by using it?

Comment: I know this because I've had the same question :) and was discussing it with the relevant product owners. I don't think it's documented anywhere, or at least I cannot find it.

Comment: Great. Thanks for clarifying. It would be nice if SDL could update this in the docs please 